# C# cycle through random letters until a word is spelled

Tags: c#, console

Ok so I want to know how I would do this in a C# console application.

Basically, I want to be able to generate a string with random letters, in a loop I want each character of the string to be replaced with another random character until a word is spelled. For example:

asdfjnb  (initial string)
soifnec
tsdkjyk
teiuhft  (random strings being generated, keeping the correct letters once generated)
tesgneg
testdha
testifd
testing  (final string)

Comment: Given that your requirement is that the random string spell an actual word, wouldn't it make more sense to just start with a dictionary and pick a word at random instead of trying to generate them randomly by brute force? Your question seems a bit like the monkeys typing Shakespeare; it'd make more sense to just start with the collected works and pick one at random, than to wait for the monkeys to finish.

Comment: Given your algorithm proposal, how will you determine when you have a 'correct' letter in the string?

Comment: To do this, a good bet is to use a dictionary and a algorithm for match strength. Then you get to have fun tweaking your algorithm for determining potential word matches and match strength.

Answer (score 1):

Another example...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        string letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        List<string> dictionary = new List<string>(new string[] { 
            "compartmentalization", "inheritance", "polymorphism", 
            "paradigm", "abstraction", "aggregration", "cryptography",
            "pseudocode", "recursion", "backtracking", "alogrithm"
        });

        string word = dictionary[r.Next(dictionary.Count)];
        List<int> indexes = new List<int>();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(letters[r.Next(letters.Length)]);
            if (sb[i] != word[i])
            {
                indexes.Add(i);
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

        while(indexes.Count > 0)
        {
            int index;
            for(int i = indexes.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                index = indexes[i];
                sb[index] = letters[r.Next(letters.Length)];
                if (sb[index] == word[index])
                {
                    indexes.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Sample output:

```
guuawfixphg
gymciirrihf
skauniqldvs
mdnefisivml
zgreeisbznk
lxzeciaewoy
nuueoixpdup
fvlejioddyi
dlaeniwlsbv
iytehitguio
irxehitlpvj
ismezitvwii
iyeesitvdxe
imfekitmope
iqjevitfcse
iukepitzcae
iqdefitntue
ipieqitpcde
ihuekituble
igzelitbade
iqmejitlbce
ixbetitifce
ivkekitkkce
itcexitdhce
iqwehitjpce
isjelitsice
iccehitujce
ikzepituece
ijeekitwace
ithewitjzce
imhewitoyce
inheeitrnce
inheiitwnce
inhewitmnce
inheiitjnce
inhepitonce
inhehitdnce
inherithnce
inheritmnce
inheritnnce
inheritxnce
inheritrnce
inherittnce
inheritsnce
inheritznce
inheritdnce
inheritmnce
inheritqnce
inheritynce
inheritvnce
inheritence
inheritqnce
inheritunce
inheritunce
inheritynce
inheritunce
inheritpnce
inheritlnce
inheritznce
inherithnce
inherittnce
inheritqnce
inheritxnce
inheritence
inheritmnce
inheritcnce
inheritpnce
inheritunce
inheritvnce
inheritcnce
inheritonce
inheritpnce
inheritgnce
inheritknce
inheritqnce
inheritfnce
inherittnce
inheritunce
inheritsnce
inheritance
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the question has a specific goal string in mind before starting this process.

Consider the string to be an array of `char`, or explicitly convert it to that. Each iteration should check each character in the string against its 'goal' char. If the current char == the goal char, then don't choose a new value for it.

```
// These specified somewhere
char[] goalstring;
char[] currentstring;

// Randomized correct logic
bool finished = false;
while (!finished)
{
    finished = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < goalstring.length; ++i)
    {
         if (currentstring[i] != goalstring[i])
         {
              finished = false;
              // this function returns a random char according to your design
              currentstring[i] = GetRandomLetter(); 
         }
    }
    // render text to screen
    PrintCurrentString(currentstring);
}
```

Getting a random character is fairly easy, you can use the `Random` class to get an `int` with a specified range, and cast it as `char`. The boundaries you choose will determine the average time it will take to reach the goal, and which character set to select from.